# Flask wtf validators Length min and max does not works

Tags: validation, flask, wtforms

I build Flask app with sqlite3 database and app.route add and app.route save

I have a problem with validators some of them works some does not works
validators.DataRequired() works
URLField() works

but validators.Length(min=1,max=15) does not works at all

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm #I aslo I also tried with Form
from wtforms import BooleanField, StringField, IntegerField, validators,SubmitField
from wtforms.fields.html5 import URLField

class AddRecValidators(FlaskForm): # <---I aslo I also tried with Form

    title = StringField('Title:',[validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(min=1,max=35,message="Title too long max 35 characters")])
    authors = StringField('Authors:',[validators.Length(min=1,max=100)])
    published_date = IntegerField('Published date:',[validators.Length(min=1,max=4)])
    isbn_or_identifier = StringField('ISBN:',[validators.Length(min=1,max=15)])
    page_count = IntegerField('Page count:',[ validators.Length(min=1,max=10000)])
    language = StringField('Language:',[ validators.Length(min=1,max=3)])
    image_links = URLField('Image links:')
    
    submit = SubmitField(label=('Add to library'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the wrong validators for the type of input you're validating.

`validators.Length()` is for strings, [see here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/#wtforms.validators.Length)

 For the integers, try using [NumberRange](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/#wtforms.validators.NumberRange)

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import BooleanField, StringField, IntegerField, validators,SubmitField
from wtforms.fields.html5 import URLField

class AddRecValidators(FlaskForm): 

    title = StringField('Title:',[validators.DataRequired(), validators.Length(min=1,max=35,message="Title too long max 35 characters")])
    authors = StringField('Authors:',[validators.Length(min=1,max=100)])
    published_date = IntegerField('Published date:',[validators.NumberRange(min=1,max=4)]) # <-- note change to NumberRange
    isbn_or_identifier = StringField('ISBN:',[validators.Length(min=1,max=15)])
    page_count = IntegerField('Page count:',[ validators.NumberRange(min=1,max=10000)]) # <-- note change to NumberRange
    language = StringField('Language:',[ validators.Length(min=1,max=3)])
    image_links = URLField('Image links:')
    
    submit = SubmitField(label=('Add to library'))
```

Also, [here are the docs for flask-wtforms validators.](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/)